# Can extension with manifest version 1 still be submitted to the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, version, manifest

When I'm trying to submit a Chrome extension to the Web Store, an error is shown. How can I submit an extension with manifest v1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html for the manifest version 1 support schedule:

> ## Manifest version 1 support schedule
>
> **Chrome 21**
>   *Beta: Early July 2012; Stable: Mid-August 2012*
>
> - The Web Store will block creation of new manifest version 1 items.
> - The Web Store will allow updates to existing manifest version 1 items.
>
> **Chrome 23**
>   *Beta: Late September 2012; Stable: Early November 2012*
>
> - The Web Store will block updates to manifest version 1 items.
> - Chrome will stop packaging manifest version 1 items (or loading them for development).
>
> **First Quarter 2013**
>
> - The Web Store will remove manifest version 1 items from the wall, search results, and category pages.
> - Notice emails will be sent to all developers with manifest version 1 items still in the store reminding them that these items will be
>     unpublished and providing update instructions.
>
> **Second Quarter 2013**
>
> - The Web Store will unpublish all manifest version 1 items.
> - Final notice emails will be sent to developers with manifest version 1 items still in the Web Store. Chrome will continue to load and run
>     installed manifest version 1 items.
>
> **Third Quarter 2013**
>
> - Chrome will stop loading or running manifest version 1 items.